# Content Allowed in iAd and Exclusions

Tags: ios, iad

I am working on implementing iAd functionality to a free app for a company that I have previously released an app for.  They are concerned that iAds could show content they feel is inappropriate for their user base.  I looked at iTunes Connect and iAd exclusions only showed ability to exclude other apps' content from being advertised, and not a way to set ratings or anything like that.  Does Apple do this automatically based off rating of the app, or is there another way?